# Troobleshoot 16.04 inexplicable total system freeze 4 hours after reboot on several NUC6i5

Tags: 16.04, kernel, intel, freeze, intel-nuc

We have recently deployed intel NUC6i5 devices in store for POS display and are encountering strange inexplicable freezes on several devices.

What is very strange is that all devices are freezing exactly 4h after boot. And there is nothing in the logs. No kernel panic, nothing in `kern.log` or `syslog`.

The system appears totally frozen (displaying the frame of the video/app it was played) and is totally unresponsive.

We have had this exact same issue on more than 20 devices (over 100), with parts from different batches, and all did freeze exactly 4h after boot (but it's not reproducible, it won't freeze every day). Some devices are playing MPV videos, while other run chromium. They are running non-stop, but are all rebooting daily at 05h05.

We're a bit clueless about what to lookout for? We tested RAM+DISK and everything seemed OK.

Is there something that could explain such total freezes? Why this exact same time 4h after boot? A verbose mode we could enable?

Thanks!

---

Update 2017-02-27:

Finally got a proper trace! It looks like I'm hitting this issue:

https://lkml.org/lkml/2015/6/11/787

But no clues to a potential fix for now.

```
DHCPREQUEST of 10.34.242.77 on eth0 to 10.32.65.65 port 67 (xid=0x30fdf923)
BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at           (null)
IP: [<ffffffff810fa7e3>] timecounter_read+0x13/0x60
PGD 0 
Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP 
Modules linked in: rfcomm ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 xt_multiport xfrm_user xfrm_algo iptable_nat nf_nat_ipv4 br_netfilter bridge stp llc aufs pl2303 usbserial bnep arc4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_skl snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_hda_codec_generic nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine dw_dmac_core snd_hda_intel iwlmvm snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core intel_rapl 8250_dw snd_hwdep mac80211 x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_pcm kvm_intel kvm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul iwlwifi ghash_clmulni_intel snd_rawmidi aesni_intel snd_seq aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper cfg80211 snd_seq_device ablk_helper cryptd snd_timer snd soundcore idma64
 virt_dma shpchp ir_lirc_codec ir_xmp_decoder lirc_dev ir_mce_kbd_decoder ir_sharp_decoder intel_lpss_pci ir_sanyo_decoder btusb ir_sony_decoder hci_uart btrtl ir_jvc_decoder ir_rc6_decoder btbcm btqca ir_rc5_decoder btintel ir_nec_decoder bluetooth mei_me rc_rc6_mce ite_cir rc_core intel_lpss_acpi intel_lpss mei acpi_pad mac_hid acpi_als kfifo_buf industrialio ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 nf_log_ipv6 xt_hl ip6t_rt nf_conntrack_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv6 ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 nf_log_ipv4 nf_log_common xt_LOG xt_limit xt_tcpudp xt_addrtype nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 xt_conntrack ip6table_filter ip6_tables nf_conntrack_netbios_ns nf_conntrack_broadcast nf_nat_ftp nf_nat nf_conntrack_ftp nf_conntrack iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables parport_pc ppdev sunrpc lp parport autofs4 i915_bpo intel_ips
 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea e1000e sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops ptp sdhci_pci ahci drm pps_core sdhci libahci video pinctrl_sunrisepoint i2c_hid pinctrl_intel hid fjes
CPU: 3 PID: 15471 Comm: kworker/3:0 Not tainted 4.4.0-64-generic #85-Ubuntu
Hardware name:                  /NUC6i5SYB, BIOS SYSKLi35.86A.0051.2016.0804.1114 08/04/2016
Workqueue: events e1000e_systim_overflow_work [e1000e]
task: ffff880031f32d00 ti: ffff8800350e8000 task.ti: ffff8800350e8000
RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff810fa7e3>]  [<ffffffff810fa7e3>] timecounter_read+0x13/0x60
RSP: 0018:ffff8800350ebdb0  EFLAGS: 00010046
RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff8800353ab7a0 RCX: 0000000000000001
RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: ffff8800350ebdf8 RDI: 0000000000000000
RBP: ffff8800350ebdb8 R08: ffff88016ed965c0 R09: 0000000000000000
R10: 000000010035ffff R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffff8800353ab780
R13: ffff8800350ebdf8 R14: 0000000000000246 R15: ffff8800353ab6d0
FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff88016ed80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
CR2: 0000000000000000 CR3: 0000000002e0a000 CR4: 00000000003406e0
Stack:
 ffff8800353ab7d0 ffff8800350ebde8 ffffffffc014d36e ffff8800353ab6d0
 ffff88016ed965c0 ffff88016ed9af00 00000000000000c0 ffff8800350ebe18
 ffffffffc014d521 ffffffff81837e26 ffff88016ed9af00 00000000a91221c0
Call Trace:
 [<ffffffffc014d36e>] e1000e_phc_gettime+0x2e/0x60 [e1000e]
 [<ffffffffc014d521>] e1000e_systim_overflow_work+0x31/0xa0 [e1000e]
 [<ffffffff81837e26>] ? __schedule+0x3b6/0xa30
 [<ffffffff8109a515>] process_one_work+0x165/0x480
 [<ffffffff8109a87b>] worker_thread+0x4b/0x4c0
 [<ffffffff8109a830>] ? process_one_work+0x480/0x480
 [<ffffffff8109a830>] ? process_one_work+0x480/0x480
 [<ffffffff810a0ba8>] kthread+0xd8/0xf0
 [<ffffffff810a0ad0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1e0/0x1e0
 [<ffffffff8183c98f>] ret_from_fork+0x3f/0x70
 [<ffffffff810a0ad0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1e0/0x1e0
Code: 00 48 d3 e0 48 83 e8 01 48 89 43 18 5b 41 5c 41 5d 5d c3 0f 1f 44 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 89 e5 53 48 8b 07 48 89 fb 48 89 c7 <ff> 10 48 8b 33 48 89 c2 48 2b 53 08 8b 4e 10 48 23 56 08 48 0f 
RIP  [<ffffffff810fa7e3>] timecounter_read+0x13/0x60
 RSP <ffff8800350ebdb0>
CR2: 0000000000000000
---[ end trace 7d024538180dff79 ]---
BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ffffffffffffffd8
IP: [<ffffffff810a1250>] kthread_data+0x10/0x20
PGD 2e0d067 PUD 2e0f067 PMD 0 
Oops: 0000 [#2] SMP 
Modules linked in: rfcomm ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 xt_multiport xfrm_user xfrm_algo iptable_nat nf_nat_ipv4 br_netfilter bridge stp llc aufs pl2303 usbserial bnep arc4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_skl snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_hda_codec_generic nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine dw_dmac_core snd_hda_intel iwlmvm snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core intel_rapl 8250_dw snd_hwdep mac80211 x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_pcm kvm_intel kvm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul iwlwifi ghash_clmulni_intel snd_rawmidi aesni_intel snd_seq aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper cfg80211 snd_seq_device ablk_helper cryptd snd_timer snd soundcore idma64
 virt_dma shpchp ir_lirc_codec ir_xmp_decoder lirc_dev ir_mce_kbd_decoder ir_sharp_decoder intel_lpss_pci ir_sanyo_decoder btusb ir_sony_decoder hci_uart btrtl ir_jvc_decoder ir_rc6_decoder btbcm btqca ir_rc5_decoder btintel ir_nec_decoder bluetooth mei_me rc_rc6_mce ite_cir rc_core intel_lpss_acpi intel_lpss mei acpi_pad mac_hid acpi_als kfifo_buf industrialio ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 nf_log_ipv6 xt_hl ip6t_rt nf_conntrack_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv6 ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 nf_log_ipv4 nf_log_common xt_LOG xt_limit xt_tcpudp xt_addrtype nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 xt_conntrack ip6table_filter ip6_tables nf_conntrack_netbios_ns nf_conntrack_broadcast nf_nat_ftp nf_nat nf_conntrack_ftp nf_conntrack iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables parport_pc ppdev sunrpc lp parport autofs4 i915_bpo intel_ips
 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea e1000e sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops ptp sdhci_pci ahci drm pps_core sdhci libahci video pinctrl_sunrisepoint i2c_hid pinctrl_intel hid fjes
CPU: 3 PID: 15471 Comm: kworker/3:0 Tainted: G      D         4.4.0-64-generic #85-Ubuntu
Hardware name:                  /NUC6i5SYB, BIOS SYSKLi35.86A.0051.2016.0804.1114 08/04/2016
task: ffff880031f32d00 ti: ffff8800350e8000 task.ti: ffff8800350e8000
RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff810a1250>]  [<ffffffff810a1250>] kthread_data+0x10/0x20
RSP: 0018:ffff8800350ebaa8  EFLAGS: 00010002
RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000003 RCX: ffffffff82109e80
RDX: 0000000000000003 RSI: 0000000000000003 RDI: ffff880031f32d00
RBP: ffff8800350ebaa8 R08: 00000000ffffffff R09: 0000000000000000
R10: ffff880031f32d60 R11: 0000000000005c00 R12: 0000000000000000
R13: 0000000000016dc0 R14: ffff880031f32d00 R15: ffff88016ed96dc0
FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff88016ed80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
CR2: 0000000000000028 CR3: 00000001653c0000 CR4: 00000000003406e0
Stack:
 ffff8800350ebac0 ffffffff8109b8b1 ffff88016ed96dc0 ffff8800350ebb10
 ffffffff818380c0 ffff8800350ebb28 ffffffff00000003 ffff880031f32d00
 ffff8800350ec000 ffff880031f333d0 ffff8800350eb6c0 0000000000000046
Call Trace:
 [<ffffffff8109b8b1>] wq_worker_sleeping+0x11/0x90
 [<ffffffff818380c0>] __schedule+0x650/0xa30
 [<ffffffff818384d5>] schedule+0x35/0x80
 [<ffffffff81084425>] do_exit+0x775/0xb00
 [<ffffffff81031c41>] oops_end+0xa1/0xd0
 [<ffffffff8106ad05>] no_context+0x135/0x380
 [<ffffffff8106afd0>] __bad_area_nosemaphore+0x80/0x1f0
 [<ffffffff8106b153>] bad_area_nosemaphore+0x13/0x20
 [<ffffffff8106b417>] __do_page_fault+0xb7/0x400
 [<ffffffffc01ecb7b>] ? __i915_wait_request+0xcb/0x660 [i915_bpo]
 [<ffffffff8106b782>] do_page_fault+0x22/0x30
 [<ffffffff8183e778>] page_fault+0x28/0x30
 [<ffffffff810fa7e3>] ? timecounter_read+0x13/0x60
 [<ffffffffc014d36e>] e1000e_phc_gettime+0x2e/0x60 [e1000e]
 [<ffffffffc014d521>] e1000e_systim_overflow_work+0x31/0xa0 [e1000e]
 [<ffffffff81837e26>] ? __schedule+0x3b6/0xa30
 [<ffffffff8109a515>] process_one_work+0x165/0x480
 [<ffffffff8109a87b>] worker_thread+0x4b/0x4c0
 [<ffffffff8109a830>] ? process_one_work+0x480/0x480
 [<ffffffff8109a830>] ? process_one_work+0x480/0x480
 [<ffffffff810a0ba8>] kthread+0xd8/0xf0
 [<ffffffff810a0ad0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1e0/0x1e0
 [<ffffffff8183c98f>] ret_from_fork+0x3f/0x70
 [<ffffffff810a0ad0>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1e0/0x1e0
Code: ff ff ff be 46 02 00 00 48 c7 c7 a0 ac cb 81 e8 c7 01 fe ff e9 a6 fe ff ff 66 90 0f 1f 44 00 00 48 8b 87 18 05 00 00 55 48 89 e5 <48> 8b 40 d8 5d c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 
RIP  [<ffffffff810a1250>] kthread_data+0x10/0x20
 RSP <ffff8800350ebaa8>
CR2: ffffffffffffffd8
---[ end trace 7d024538180dff7a ]---
Fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed!
```

---

Here is the end log of `kern.log`:

```
Jan 26 05:05:32 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485403532.2307] manager: (docker0): new Bridge device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
Jan 26 05:05:32 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485403532.2466] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/docker0, iface: docker0)
Jan 26 05:05:32 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485403532.2466] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/docker0, iface: docker0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Jan 26 05:05:32 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485403532.3475] device (docker0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed') [10 20 41]
Jan 26 05:05:32 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485403532.3490] keyfile: add connection in-memory (ce78eed6-7fa3-4e1b-a835-30fc21b5165a,"docker0")
Jan 26 05:05:32 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485403532.3497] device (docker0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed') [20 30 41]
Jan 26 05:05:32 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485403532.3512] device (docker0): Activation: starting connection 'docker0' (ce78eed6-7fa3-4e1b-a835-30fc21b5165a)
Jan 26 05:05:32 player-ccaa kernel: [   14.224889] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): docker0: link is not ready
Jan 26 05:05:32 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485403532.3551] device (docker0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Jan 26 05:05:32 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485403532.3669] device (docker0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jan 26 05:05:32 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485403532.3686] device (docker0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Jan 26 05:05:32 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485403532.3760] device (docker0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none') [70 80 0]
Jan 26 05:05:32 player-ccaa kernel: [   14.253721] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:f4:4d:30:65:04:da:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:382f:9166:a48e:182a DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=818314 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
Jan 26 05:05:32 player-ccaa kernel: [   14.253735] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:f4:4d:30:65:04:da:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:382f:9166:a48e:182a DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=757395 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
Jan 26 05:05:32 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485403532.3852] device (docker0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none') [80 90 0]
Jan 26 05:05:32 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485403532.3865] device (docker0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Jan 26 05:05:32 player-ccaa kernel: [   14.264506] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:f4:4d:30:65:04:da:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:382f:9166:a48e:182a DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=818314 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
Jan 26 05:05:32 player-ccaa kernel: [   14.264518] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:f4:4d:30:65:04:da:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:382f:9166:a48e:182a DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=757395 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
Jan 26 05:05:32 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485403532.3992] device (docker0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Jan 26 05:05:32 player-ccaa kernel: [   14.282714] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:c224:80e3:560c:97d7 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=69955 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
Jan 26 05:05:32 player-ccaa kernel: [   14.282735] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:c224:80e3:560c:97d7 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=909475 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
Jan 26 05:05:32 player-ccaa kernel: [   14.293332] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:c224:80e3:560c:97d7 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=69955 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
Jan 26 05:05:32 player-ccaa kernel: [   14.293356] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:c224:80e3:560c:97d7 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=909475 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
Jan 26 05:05:33 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485403533.1294] WiFi hardware radio set enabled
Jan 26 05:05:33 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485403533.1294] WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Jan 26 05:05:33 player-ccaa kernel: [   15.037186] nf_conntrack: automatic helper assignment is deprecated and it will be removed soon. Use the iptables CT target to attach helpers instead.
Jan 26 05:05:33 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485403533.5487] manager: startup complete
Jan 26 05:05:40 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485403540.1485] manager: (tun0): new Tun device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4)
Jan 26 05:05:40 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485403540.1548] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)
Jan 26 05:05:40 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485403540.1554] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Jan 26 05:05:40 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485403540.1559] device (tun0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed') [10 20 41]
Jan 26 05:05:40 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485403540.1576] keyfile: add connection in-memory (4a5b5eae-6b0c-4887-8500-78a2526a94b2,"tun0")
Jan 26 05:05:40 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485403540.1585] device (tun0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed') [20 30 41]
Jan 26 05:05:40 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485403540.1628] device (tun0): Activation: starting connection 'tun0' (4a5b5eae-6b0c-4887-8500-78a2526a94b2)
Jan 26 05:05:40 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485403540.1641] device (tun0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Jan 26 05:05:40 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485403540.1649] device (tun0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jan 26 05:05:40 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485403540.1657] device (tun0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Jan 26 05:05:40 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485403540.1670] device (tun0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none') [70 80 0]
Jan 26 05:05:40 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485403540.1676] device (tun0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none') [80 90 0]
Jan 26 05:05:40 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485403540.1682] device (tun0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Jan 26 05:05:40 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485403540.1757] device (tun0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Jan 26 05:05:48 player-ccaa kernel: [   30.612550] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=f4:4d:30:64:50:ef:c4:72:95:0e:0e:47:08:00 SRC=51.255.59.184 DST=10.34.210.76 LEN=123 TOS=0x18 PREC=0x00 TTL=52 ID=61912 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=60296 WINDOW=32038 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Jan 26 05:06:31 player-ccaa kernel: [   73.684805] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=f4:4d:30:64:50:ef:c4:72:95:0e:0e:47:08:00 SRC=51.255.59.184 DST=10.34.210.76 LEN=123 TOS=0x18 PREC=0x00 TTL=52 ID=61913 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=60296 WINDOW=32038 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Jan 26 05:07:57 player-ccaa kernel: [  159.829079] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=f4:4d:30:64:50:ef:c4:72:95:0e:0e:47:08:00 SRC=51.255.59.184 DST=10.34.210.76 LEN=123 TOS=0x18 PREC=0x00 TTL=52 ID=61914 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=60296 WINDOW=32038 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Jan 26 05:24:46 player-ccaa kernel: [ 1168.341626] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: azx_get_response timeout, switching to polling mode: last cmd=0x205f3100
Jan 26 05:55:26 player-ccaa kernel: [ 3008.471662] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: IRQ timing workaround is activated for card #0. Suggest a bigger bdl_pos_adj.
Jan 26 06:12:44 player-ccaa kernel: [ 4046.651139] perf interrupt took too long (2538 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
Jan 26 07:06:32 player-ccaa kernel: [ 7274.913169] traps: pool[28796] trap int3 ip:7f9213409a6b sp:7f91f081b6f0 error:0
Jan 26 08:13:38 player-ccaa kernel: [11301.034720] perf interrupt took too long (5025 > 5000), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 25000
Jan 26 08:44:57 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485416697.5313]   address 10.34.210.76
Jan 26 08:44:57 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485416697.5337]   plen 25 (255.255.255.128)
Jan 26 08:44:57 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485416697.5338]   gateway 10.34.210.1
Jan 26 08:44:57 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485416697.5338]   server identifier 10.33.85.50
Jan 26 08:44:57 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485416697.5338]   lease time 28800
Jan 26 08:44:57 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485416697.5339]   nameserver '10.32.24.93'
Jan 26 08:44:57 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485416697.5339]   nameserver '10.33.81.251'
Jan 26 08:44:57 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485416697.5339]   nameserver '10.32.24.94'
Jan 26 08:44:57 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485416697.5339]   domain name 'vuitton.lvmh'
Jan 26 08:44:57 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485416697.5340]   wins '10.32.24.93'
Jan 26 08:44:57 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485416697.5340]   wins '10.33.81.251'
Jan 26 08:44:57 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485416697.5340]   wins '10.32.24.94'
Jan 26 08:44:57 player-ccaa NetworkManager[893]: <info>  [1485416697.5350] dhcp4 (eth0): state changed bound -> bound
Feb 15 06:04:36 player-ccaa kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Feb 15 06:04:36 player-ccaa kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Feb 15 06:04:36 player-ccaa kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
Feb 15 06:04:36 player-ccaa kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 4.4.0-59-generic (buildd@lgw01-11) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ) #80-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 6 17:47:47 UTC 2017 (Ubuntu 4.4.0-59.80-generic 4.4.35)
Feb 15 06:04:36 player-ccaa kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-59-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=1f60f9c9-bbf1-45df-bdc3-9b4da883839e ro quiet splash net.ifnames=0 vt.handoff=7
Feb 15 06:04:36 player-ccaa kernel: [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
Feb 15 06:04:36 player-ccaa kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
Feb 15 06:04:36 player-ccaa kernel: [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
Feb 15 06:04:36 player-ccaa kernel: [    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
Feb 15 06:04:36 player-ccaa kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: xstate_offset[2]:  576, xstate_sizes[2]:  256
Feb 15 06:04:36 player-ccaa kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: xstate_offset[3]:  960, xstate_sizes[3]:   64
Feb 15 06:04:36 player-ccaa kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: xstate_offset[4]: 1024, xstate_sizes[4]:   64
Feb 15 06:04:36 player-ccaa kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x01: 'x87 floating point registers'
Feb 15 06:04:36 player-ccaa kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x02: 'SSE registers'
Feb 15 06:04:36 player-ccaa kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x04: 'AVX registers'
Feb 15 06:04:36 player-ccaa kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x08: 'MPX bounds registers'
Feb 15 06:04:36 player-ccaa kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x10: 'MPX CSR'
Feb 15 06:04:36 player-ccaa kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Enabled xstate features 0x1f, context size is 1088 bytes, using 'standard' format.
Feb 15 06:04:36 player-ccaa kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Using 'eager' FPU context switches.
```

The end of `syslog`:

```
Jan 26 09:01:11 player-ccaa wpa_supplicant[1098]: wlan0: Failed to initiate sched scan
Jan 26 09:02:14 player-ccaa wpa_supplicant[1098]: wlan0: Failed to initiate sched scan
Jan 26 09:03:18 player-ccaa wpa_supplicant[1098]: wlan0: Failed to initiate sched scan
Jan 26 09:04:21 player-ccaa wpa_supplicant[1098]: wlan0: Failed to initiate sched scan
Jan 26 09:05:23 player-ccaa wpa_supplicant[1098]: wlan0: Failed to initiate sched scan
---
Feb 15 06:04:36 player-ccaa rsyslogd-2222: command 'KLogPermitNonKernelFacility' is currently not permitted - did you already set it via a RainerScript command (v6+ config)? [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2222 ]
Feb 15 06:04:36 player-ccaa rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 108
Feb 15 06:04:36 player-ccaa rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 104
Feb 15 06:04:36 player-ccaa rsyslogd-2039: Could not open output pipe '/dev/xconsole':: No such file or directory [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2039 ]
Feb 15 06:04:36 player-ccaa rsyslogd-2007: action 'action 10' suspended, next retry is Wed Feb 15 06:05:06 2017 [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Feb 15 06:04:36 player-ccaa systemd-modules-load[238]: Inserted module 'lp'
Feb 15 06:04:36 player-ccaa systemd-modules-load[238]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Feb 15 06:04:36 player-ccaa systemd-modules-load[238]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
Feb 15 06:04:36 player-ccaa loadkeys[225]: Loading /etc/console-setup/cached.kmap.gz
Feb 15 06:04:36 player-ccaa systemd[1]: Started Set console keymap.
Feb 15 06:04:36 player-ccaa systemd[1]: Started Apply Kernel Variables.
Feb 15 06:04:36 player-ccaa systemd[1]: Started Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Feb 15 06:04:36 player-ccaa systemd[1]: Starting udev Kernel Device Manager...
Feb 15 06:04:36 player-ccaa ureadahead[217]: ureadahead:/lib/modprobe.d/blacklist_linux_4.4.0-36-generic.conf: No such file or directory
Feb 15 06:04:36 player-ccaa systemd-udevd[291]: Network interface NamePolicy= disabled on kernel command line, ignoring.
```

Comment: Weird...  Maybe see if there are any BIOS updates available, and also try the latest stable Mesa version from here: https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/pkppa

Comment: Have you made any progress in finding a fix for this? Seem to see it on some of my hardware too.