# Freeze 4h after reboot/startup on Intel NUC6i5

Tags: 16.04, freeze

We experience freezes of PCs exactly 4h after startup/reboot.

Description:

- ~100 Intel NUC6i5 PCs running on Ubuntu 16.04 displaying pictures and videos all the time (a so called digital signage system)
- randomly 1-3 pcs freeze each day exactly 4h after startup/reboot. They go offline, are completely unresponsive and picture is freezed.
- some older versions of PCs do not show this behaviour, thus we tried to experiment with BIOS (actually downgrading BIOS) -> no effect
- We do not see any helpful information in any logs, only NULLs in form of ^@^@^ in moment of freeze.
- Kernel update did not have an effect

Similar problem is described here with no documented solution:
[Troobleshoot 16.04 inexplicable total system freeze 4 hours after reboot on several NUC6i5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/884099/troobleshoot-16-04-inexplicable-total-system-freeze-4-hours-after-reboot-on-seve)

We can neither change hardware nor software - but idea of these PCs is to run independently. No user is supposed to restart them regularly.

Any ideas what can cause such a strange behaviour